# Fail to upload file to AWS S3 Bucket

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I have been tearing my hair out for the last couple of hours and I can't figure out what I am doing wrong.

I setup a free Amazon S3 account, created a Bucket and using the IAM tool I create an User and assigned him to a group with the following policies:

```
AmazonS3FullAccess and AWSConnector
```

I am trying to run a Java example as follows:

```
 public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    AmazonS3 s3client = new AmazonS3Client(
            new PropertiesFileCredentialsProvider("credentials.properties"));
    try {
        File file = new File("myfile");
        s3client.putObject(new PutObjectRequest("bucket", "key", file));

    } catch (AmazonServiceException ase) {
        ...
    } catch (AmazonClientException ace) {
        ...
    }
}
```

The file is an empty text file.

When I run this code I get this stacktrace:

```
java.net.ProtocolException: Server rejected operation
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.expect100Continue(HttpURLConnection.java:1217) ~[na:1.8.0_31]
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getOutputStream0(HttpURLConnection.java:1296) ~[na:1.8.0_31]
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getOutputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1257) ~[na:1.8.0_31]
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getOutputStream(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:250) ~[na:1.8.0_31]
    at com.amazonaws.http.UrlHttpClient.writeContentToConnection(UrlHttpClient.java:128) ~[aws-android-sdk-core-2.2.11.jar:na]
    at com.amazonaws.http.UrlHttpClient.execute(UrlHttpClient.java:65) ~[aws-android-sdk-core-2.2.11.jar:na]
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.executeHelper(AmazonHttpClient.java:353) [aws-android-sdk-core-2.2.11.jar:na]
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.execute(AmazonHttpClient.java:196) [aws-android-sdk-core-2.2.11.jar:na]
    at com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3Client.invoke(AmazonS3Client.java:4212) [aws-android-sdk-s3-2.2.11.jar:na]
    at com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3Client.putObject(AmazonS3Client.java:1619) [aws-android-sdk-s3-2.2.11.jar:na]
```

Any ideas for what might be going on?

#### UPDATE

If I programatically create a new Bucket I can upload files to it successfully.
I deleted my first bucket which I created on the managemente console and tried recreating it programatically but now it says the requested bucket name is not available.

I don't know why I can't use manually created buckets (created using the managemente console).

Comment: Check the permission of  the buckets which is created using the AWS console and programmatic way. I think its a permission issues.

Comment: Please update if the above mentioned solution worked. I am facing the same exception intermittently